# Org chart layout algorithm with a special need

Tags: algorithm, layout, tree, diagram, orgchart

Is the John Q. Walker II [node positioning algorithm](http://www.cs.unc.edu/techreports/89-034.pdf) able to find the node positions for an org chart like below, where each node can either have their children displayed stacked (see node 1.4, 1.4.2, 1.3.1...), or "Org" style (as node 1 and 1.3)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can heavily adapt the algorithm, but in general the answer is "No". The fundamental assumption of this node positioning algorithm is all nodes of same level in the tree have same Y coordinate.

Comment: You made me realize I used a very bad example, since I do want all nodes on the same levels in the tree. I updated my diagram for that purpose.

Comment: @GregForel - No, in your example the RFP, Selection, and the guid nodes  at the lower right hand side are on the same hierarchical level (3rd from root) but all have different y-coordinates. This vertical arrangement of a subtree is exactly what this algorithm *cannot* do. You will need a more sophisticated implementation like here: [demo](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/2.0/complete/orgchart/index.html)

Comment: @Sebastian - OK, got it. Is there a name for a layout algorithm that allows such positioning? I coded the algorithm in the image, but there are sometimes issues both in positioning and performance, so I wanted to find one to compare where I went wrong.